# In Qt, how do I add qstrings within a for loop to be appended to each other and put inside a single message box?

Tags: c++, string, qt, messagebox

```
for(size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx){
   libusb_device *device = list[idx];
   libusb_device_descriptor desc = {0};
   rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
   assert(rc == 0);
   //Print out desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct
   QString VendorID = QString("%1").arg(desc.idVendor, 0, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
   QString ProductID = QString("%1").arg(desc.idProduct, 0, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
   QString USB_BUS = QString("%1").arg(libusb_get_bus_number(device)).rightJustified(1, ' ');
   QString USB_DEVICE = QString("%1").arg(libusb_get_device_address(device)).rightJustified(1, ' ');

   QMessageBox::information(this, "USB Connection Status", QString("VendorID:ProductID = %1:%2 | Bus: %3 Device: %4\n").arg(VendorID).arg(ProductID).arg(USB_BUS).arg(USB_DEVICE));
}
```

Here is the code I have written. As you can tell I'm a bit confused to use QString within a for loop. What I ideally want is a SINGLE dialogue box that can contain a for-looped qstring message. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Get the QMessageBox out of the for loop. Put it right after the loop. Collect your message in a single QString and append on each iteration.

Comment: Just append to a single string using `+=`

Comment: As Drew McGowen mentioned it's possible to make something like

QString string;
for(..condition..)
{
    string += ...; //add whatever you want to add
}

just += every turn what you need and put it into the dialogue after the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for(size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx){
   libusb_device *device = list[idx];
   libusb_device_descriptor desc = {0};
   rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
   assert(rc == 0);
   //Print out desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct
   QString VendorID = QString("%1").arg(desc.idVendor, 0, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
   QString ProductID = QString("%1").arg(desc.idProduct, 0, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
   QString USB_BUS = QString("%1").arg(libusb_get_bus_number(device)).rightJustified(1, ' ');
   QString USB_DEVICE = QString("%1").arg(libusb_get_device_address(device)).rightJustified(1, ' ');

   USB_STATUS += QString("VendorID:ProductID = %1:%2 | Bus: %3 Device: %4\n").arg(VendorID).arg(ProductID).arg(USB_BUS).arg(USB_DEVICE);
}
QMessageBox::information(this, "USB Connection Status", USB_STATUS);
```

Yup += did it for me along with putting the QMessageBox outside the loop. Just gonna post this here in case anyone finds themselves in the same situation as myself in the future.